# Using a list comprehension: Do calculations on elements of lists that are not a string or element of another list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I've got two lists l1 and l2 with elements of different types like this:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,'4']
l2 = [1,2]
```

I'd like to do calculations of each element in l1 that are not in l2, and not of type string. So I'm wondering if it's possible to isolate integers and strings in a list comprehension somehow.

First of all, here is an example where each element e in l1 is added to itself if e is not in l2:

```
# code
r = [e+e for e in l1 if e not in l2]
print(r)

# result
# [6, '44']
```

Here '4' is repeated and not added since it's a character, but I'd like to ignore that element. So I was thinking that I could isolate elements that had type(e)==int.

A naive attempt:

```
# code
r = [e+e for e in l1 if type(e)==int not in l2]

# output
[2, 4, 6]
```

Here, '4' in l1 is ignored seemingly because it's not an integer, but 3 is added to itself even though it's not in l2.

What's going on here (besides the fact that I don't understand list comprehensions)?

Comment: `type(e) == int not in l2` expands to `(type(e) == int) and (int not in l2)`. Even if that didn't happen, you'd be checking whether the boolean result of comparing `type(e)` to `int` was or wasn't in the list `l2`, which doesn't make much sense. Did you mean `isinstance(e, int) and e not in l2`? This isn't a list comprehension problem, you'd see the same behaviour if you unrolled it to a classic `for` loop.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Whoever downvotes this, could you please explain why do you do that? What part of SO asking questions guidelines this does not conform to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for both conditions `type(e)==int` and `e not in l2` , use `and` operator

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,'4']
>>> l2 = [1,2]
>>> 
>>> r = [e+e for e in l1 if type(e)==int and e not in l2]
>>> 
>>> r
[6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isinstance`

**Ex:**

```
l1 = [1,2,3,'4']
l2 = [1,2]

r = [e+e for e in l1 if (e not in l2) and (isinstance(e, int))]
print(r)
```

**Output:**

```
[6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Some options here, using `and`:

```
r = [e+e for e in l1 if e not in l2 and type(e)==int]
```

filtering first:

```
r = [e+e for e in filter(lambda x: type(x)==int, l1) if e not in l2]
```

filter all, which is the same as the first version(but would be less efficient in python2):

```
r = [e+e for e in filter(lambda x: type(x)==int and x not in l2, l1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `set`:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,'4']
l2 = [1,2]
print([e+e for e in [x for x in l1 if not x in set(l1).intersection(l2)] if type(e) == int])
```

Output:

```
[6]
```

Comment: this will avoid duplicated numbers

Answer (score 1):

If that is a real task and you care about solving it, I'd highly suggest you to use sets to get rid of unneeded elements, since that will give you linear time complexity instead of quadratic.

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3, '4']
>>> l2 = [1, 2]
>>> s1 = set(l1)
>>> s2 = set(l2)
>>> result = [x * 2 for x in s1.intersection(s2)]
>>> result
[2, 4]
```

Your original question was already answered both in comments and answers.

EDIT: In case you're interested in complexity explanation: what you're doing in your code, you're looking up each and every element of `l1` in `l2`. Suppose `l1` has `n` elements, and `l2` has `m` elements. To lookup something in a list or an array, you *must* look at every element in that list, so looking up an element in `l2` has `O(m)` complexity. You're doing that for each element of `l1`, so `n` times. Thus total complexity of building that list you need to double elements of is `O(nm)`.

With sets, however, each lookup is `O(1)`, because essentially it's a hash table. You'll still have to loop through your `l1`, so `O(n)`, but now lookups are constant time, so `O(1)`. That gives us a total of `O(n)`.

If you're supposed to have duplicating elements in your lists, this gets a bit trickier, but you still can get away with using dictionaries or Counters.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this! I'm really tempted to delete the question since it seems i'ts going to be a one way ticket to downvote-town. But seeing the effort some of you are making to explain these things, I don't have any choice but to let it stand. Thanks again!

Comment: @vestland, no worries. I wouldn't worry about 'downvote-town' as you're not going to lose a lot of reputation due to that; however, I don't really get why is it downvoted. A legit question with minimal reproducable example included, you showed what you did... makes an alright question to me.

Comment: I thought so too. I guess it was just considered too easy for some.

Comment: @vestland, should not be the case. SO is not a place for tough questions only. Might be a duplicate, sure; but downvoting is not an adequate reaction to a duplicate question.